# Javascript Maxlength input after comma

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to translate this jquery code into javascript?

```
$("#field").keypress(function (evt) {
if (evt.which == 46) {
    $(this).val($(this).val() + ',');
    evt.preventDefault();
}

//The input of more than 2 numbers after the decimal point is prevented
var foo = $(this).val();
if( !foo.match(/^(\d)*,?(\d){0,1}$/) ){
     evt.preventDefault(); 
}
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Pisi2012/uSw5b/7/)

Thanx in advance!

Comment: jQuery is a JavaScript library, so code that uses jQuery already runs in JavaScript.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. If you want to learn how you might want to read some books/tutorials/whatever to familiarize yourself with JavaScript. If you want us to do all the coding for you, then you have come to the wrong place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i have found a solution. Hope it helps anybody

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function decimals(that) {
  var s = that.value;
  var i = s.indexOf(".");
  if (i < 0 || s.substr(i+1).length < 2) return;
  alert("Only 1 digit to the right of the decimal are allowed!");
  that.value = s.substring(0,i+2);
  }
</script>

<input type="text" size="5" maxlength="5" onkeyup="decimals(this)">
```

best wishes

Answer (score 0):

check this code http://jsfiddle.net/s62W5/ may help you

```
var x=document.getElementById("field");
 x.onkeydown = function(e){

 var keyPress;

 if (typeof event !== 'undefined') {
   keyPress = event.keyCode;
 }
 else if (e) {
   keyPress = e.which;
 }
  if (keyPress == 46) {
  x.value= x.value + ',';

 }
};
```

Comment: Hi and thank you for your answer, but it seems that it doesn't work